# Are java standard packages supported for Quarkus native image?

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm building an app using quarkus. And im using javax.xml.soap* packages and many other classes which is located under rt.jar . My code is working without error while running standard JVM mode. But they said  that i couldnt build a native image with those libraries.I dont have graalvm to try for it and the process of building native image is took very long with the free version. Actually there is no good enough documentation to understand how this works.So how can i use these libraries with the native image?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Quarkus is just using GraalVM native image for the AOT compilation providing the configurations for the libraries in the extensions. So this is not a question about Quarkus but using `javax.xml.soap` in the native images.

There might be some issue with the xml processing. GraalVM recently added `jaxb` support.

The best course of action currently is to open an issue at Quarkus is just using GraalVM native image for the AOT compilation so this is not a question about Quarkus but using `javax.xml.soap` in the native images.

There might be issues with the xml processing classes when used in GraalVM native images. For example, GraalVM just recently added `jaxb` support.

The best course of action currently is to open an issue at [github.com/oracle/graal/issues](http://github.com/oracle/graal/issues) and describe what is happening. And it'll be fixed.

Comment: yes my question is not about Quarkus but its about creating native image by GraalVM. how can we learn which packages are supported by the GraalVM?

Comment: I think if there's no active issue in the github repository, it should work? If it doesn't it's a but and you should create an issue? There are some known limitations to what is currently possible, documented here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md